# Regression equation of a stacked difference-in-difference analysis in R

Tags: r, regression, equation, stacked

I got a code for a stacked difference-in-difference analysis with fixed effects and now I have a problem with creating the regression equation.

Here you find the code in R:

reg.3 <- feols( log(avg_rating) ~ post:treated + post:treated:i(mainstream, ref=0) | exp_book + exp_date, data = df)

avg_rating .... average rating,
post  ..... binary factor (before and after event),
treated .... binary factor (treated and control),
mainstream .... binary factor (niche and mainstream),
exp_book ... fixed effect (unit),
exp_date ... fixed effect (time),
df ... dataframe

The regression equation which I started to create:

log(avg_ratingsijt) = β1treatedij ×postt+β2treatedij ×postt×mainstreami+μij +τtj +εijt

μij ... fixed effect (unit)
τtj ... fixed effect (time)
i .... book
j ... experiment
t ... time

I got this feedback and I don't know what I should do now:
What is the difference between beta1 and beta 2? You have two treated x posts as far as I can see.

I need the full regression equation for this experiment and I don't know how to implement the feedback.

Thank you in advance for your help.